# How to write PHP code containing {} in blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my syntax? I am trying to write this set of php code in the a laravel blade file

```
  @php  $identifiedIndex = $relevantTicketFlows->search(function($query) use ($data->ticket_flow_id){return $query->id == $data->ticket_flow_id;});
                                                            echo '<p> $relevantTicketFlows[$identifiedIndex] </p> '
                                                        @endphp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should really avoid this kind of behavior, Laravel uses *MVC* pattern, and having logic in a view is the devil.

Then, I think you just have a syntax error:

```
use ($data->ticket_flow_id){return $query->id
```

You can't have this in a `use` (I'm pretty sure), try:

```
use ($data) {
   // access $data->ticket_flow_id inside closure
```

Answer (score 0):

For the js

```
const user = '{{$user->id}}'
```

For the html

```
<a href="{{ route('get_user', ['user' => $user->id]) }}">
```